# Xcode auto-generated unit tests

Tags: swift, xcode

Coming from an Android background I am searching for a way to automatically generate the unit test method signatures in Xcode. I know this is supported in other IDEs and languages too, like Pycharm and Goland.

[image]

Is there anything similar in xCode or Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, No. Xcode has no such feature. You just have to write the test "by hand".

Comment: You might try AppCode if you want an iOS IDE that is smart about that kind of thing.